# How to count a radius of a polygon

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a Polygon (shapely) and the centroid of this Polygon (with longitude and latitude).
Is there any way to count radius of the Polygon?

Comment: The only type of polygon which has a radius is a circle. This is not something which is *counted*, but can be *computed*. Geodesic circles are a special case, but you can even locate the center with only vertices and a Geodetic Problem function library. Please [Edit] the question to show what you have tried, and give details on where you are stuck.

Comment: i have not tried yet, i am trying to understand, is it in general possible? I found, that it's possible to compute a radius of a regualr polygon(which has sides all equal to each other), but it is probably not possible for irregular polygons, which i have to deal with: https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html

Comment: I have located the centroid and radius of irregular geodetic circles and centroid, semi-major, semi-minor, and orientation of irregular ellipses using nothing but Java. It is certainly possible, if the figure is circle-ish or ellipse-ish. (you can even calculate the deviation from a perfect circle or perfect ellipse). But [Shapely only has Cartesian support](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266796/geojson-to-shapely-geodesic-parameter/266830#266830), so you need to expand your scope to GeoPandas or write your own Forward and Reverse solvers (not recommended).

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: [How to count a radius of a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59195515/7851470)